ORA-00997 illegal use of Long datatype while selecting data with Spring Data JPA
I recently updated an application to SpringBoot 3.2 with Hibernate 6 and encountered and issue selecting data by using repository.findById() out of an Oracle database with column type LONG RAW containing a hex string.

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select cc1_0.user,cc1_0.type,cc1_0.version,cc1_0.data_size,cc1_0.data from plan cc1_0 where (cc1_0.user,cc1_0.type,cc1_0.version) in ((?,?,?))] [ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

If I copy the query in SQLDeveloper and fill in the parameters, it can be executed and shows the results.
I cannot change the column type, because I only have read access. It is not possible to create a view, because to_lob() can only be used in insert statements.
I tried using prefer_long_raw flag, but with no success, the error remained.
Entity
@Lob
@Column(name = "DATA", nullable = true)
private byte[] data;

application.yml
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
        dialect.oracle.prefer_long_raw: true

ChatGPT suggested to use native queries, but the entity has some relationships and different data types, so it would be a little bit complex.
Any other suggestions?

Can you show SQL statement that cause the error?

Sure, sorry, I added the query which is shown by the exception

How that column declared?

CREATE TABLE "PLAN"
"USER" NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"TYPE" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"VERSION" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
"DATA" LONG RAW,
"DATA_SIZE" NUMBER (8, 0),
PRIMARY KEY ("USER", "TYPE", "VERSION")

You can use @ColumnTransformer(read="TO_LOB(DATA)") on that column.
It will use provided SQL to extract value for this column.
I didn't checked it. Please let me know if converter is wrong.

Thank you for your effort, but I think it will not work, because Oracle documentation says "You can apply this function only to a LONG or LONG RAW column, and only in the select list of a subquery in an INSERT statement." But I will try with TO_BLOB, too, because "You cannot use this function within a PL/SQL package. Instead use the TO_CLOB (character) or TO_BLOB (raw) functions."

With TO_LOB I got ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got LONG BINARY, with TO_BLOB I got ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY got LONG BINARY

Unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce problem :( https://onecompiler.com/oracle/42gsvdqny

I found a workaround by using nativeQuery, that I want to share with others:
JPA repository
public interface PlanRepository extends JpaRepository<Plan, PlanId> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM PLAN p WHERE p.user = ?1 AND p.type = ?2 AND p.version = ?3",
        nativeQuery = true)
    Plan findByIdNative(Integer user, String type, String version);
}

To prevent an already closed stream IO exception, we have to read the whole data, by setting an option to datasource properties.
application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name:  oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        use-fetch-size-with-long-column: true

So if you want to use this property, make sure that the LONG columns you are retrieving are not too big or you may run out of memory.
